# Is there anyway to turn off comments in Java EE 1.4 JSPs?

Tags: java, jsp, comments

I know in JSF there are ways to turn off comments elegantly, is this possible in JSPs?

Comment: Comments of what? Comments inside of your source code? No, that is not possible. And why would anyone do that?

Comment: When the JSP is displayed to the user. You would not want the user to see // this should be null ?

Comment: use scriptlet comments instead of html comments. <%-- like this --%>

Comment: rofl ... JSPs are not displayed to the user. They are compiled on the server and only the HTML is sent to the user. As Nathan says: use code comments and not html comments.

Comment: JSP is compiled into a Servlet, you needn't tell me that, or so sarcastically. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately some kind of scripting mass-replace is probably your best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comments will be removed when the jsp is parsed,

```
<%-- Sekret Comment --%>
```

If you need to do it to a lot of files, [htmlcompressor](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) can be run in your build script and it removes comments as part of it's minification process.

Comment: Andrew, thanks. I have 600 source files, i need to know if there is a out of the box solution, just like JSF, where i can specify in the xml to simply turn on/off any comments without touching the source.

Comment: Perhaps you can use perl script to transform the comments?